# Deducing the Pythagorean Theorem from a particular dissection

Tags: euclidean-geometry

How can I deduce the pythagorean theorem from the follow image?

[image]

I have been draw some parallels and I got the figure but I don't know how to deduct, some hint?

Answer (score 1):

Note that each colored piece in the big square with side length $c$ appears once in the small squares with side lengths $a$ and $b$. From this, the sum of the areas of the small squares is equal to the area of the big square, or $\boxed{a^{2} + b^{2} = c^{2}}$

Comment: There's a *little* bit of work to do to show that the same-colored polygons actually have equal areas, but it's not difficult.